# memberof not working with ldapmodify

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldapmodule

I have an openldap instance with the memberof and refint modules configured.

The memberof overlay is configured like this:

```
dn: cn=module{1},cn=config
cn: module{1}
objectClass: olcModuleList
olcModuleLoad: memberof
olcModulePath: /usr/lib64/openldap

dn: olcOverlay={1}memberof,olcDatabase={1}bdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcConfig
objectClass: olcMemberOf
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: top
olcOverlay: memberof
olcMemberOfDangling: ignore
olcMemberOfRefInt: TRUE
olcMemberOfGroupOC: customGroup
olcMemberOfMemberAD: member
olcmemberOfMemberOfAD: memberof
#olcMemberof-dangling-error:
#olcMemberof-dn:
```

The refint overlay is configured like this:

```
dn: olcOverlay={1}refint,olcDatabase={1}bdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcConfig
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcRefintConfig
objectClass: top
olcOverlay: {1}refint
olcRefintAttribute: memberof member
```

I created a user `john` and a group of objectClass `customGroup`. My groupmembership attribute is set to default, which is `member`.

When I create the group and with `john`, everything works fine and my `ldapsearch` command returns the `memberof` attribute of the user `john`.

But when I create an empty group and add `john` afterwards with the `ldapmodify` command, the memberof overlay does not fire and the `ldapsearch` command does not return the `memberof` attribute.

Is this the intended behaviour? I thought the refint overlay would handle the modifications on the group. How do I configure the modules correctly, so that they will return the `memberof` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Every overlay has to be loaded. Try to add to the entry

```
dn: cn=module{1},cn=config
cn: module{1}
```

The attribute :

`olcModuleLoad: refint`